# Get files from Jar which is on the repository without downloading the whole Jar from Java

Tags: java, search, jar, download

I would like to access the jar file on the repository, search inside it for the certain files, retrieve those files and store them on my hard disc. I don't want to download the whole jar and then to search for it.

So let's assume I have the address of the Jar. Can someone provide me with the code for the rest of the problem?

```
 public void searchInsideJar(final String jarUrl, final String artifactId,
        final String artifactVersion) {
    InputStream is = null;
    OutputStream outStream = null;
    JarInputStream jis = null;
    int i = 1;
    try {
        String strDirectory = "C:/Users/ilijab/" + artifactId   +artifactVersion;

        // Create one directory
        boolean success = (new File(strDirectory)).mkdir();
        if (success) {
            System.out.println("Directory: " + strDirectory + " created");
        }

        is = new URL(jarUrl).openStream();
        jis = new JarInputStream(is);

        while (true) {
            JarEntry ent = jis.getNextJarEntry();
            if (ent == null) {
                break;
            }
            if (ent.isDirectory()) {
                continue;
            }
            if (ent.getName().contains("someFile")) {
                outStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(
                        strDirectory + "\\" + "someFile" + i));
                while(ent.)
                System.out.println("**************************************************************");
                System.out.println(i);
                i++;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
}
```

So, in upper code, how can I save the file I found(the last if) into directory.

Comment: What do you mean by "repository"? A Maven repository?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that by "repository", you mean a Maven repository, then i'm afraid this can't be done. Maven repositories let you download artifacts, like jar files, but won't look inside them for you.