# Load a class from a jar, in another machine, without downloading the whole Jar

Tags: java, applet, classloader

I have seen two questions with same subject, but none of them seem to answer my question.
[How to load a jar from an URL without downloading it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14751584/how-to-load-a-jar-from-an-url-without-downloading-it)
[Get files from Jar which is on the repository without downloading the whole Jar from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9231197/get-files-from-jar-which-is-on-the-repository-without-downloading-the-whole-jar)

I, in an applet, would like to download classes from a Jar file inside the server, but without downloading the whole jar file. 
Is it possible?

Comment: That will depend.  Do you have access rights to read the Jar and perform class loading from within the Applet.  The class will need to be downloaded and loaded on the client side.  Downloading would just mean loading the class bytes into memory, but you need to have the appropriate security permissions to do it.

Comment: A JAR file is actually the ZIP file format with some extra rules (manifest first, etc).  Therefore, you can download just the Central Directory, the Local Header, and the class file itself with code that understands the structure of a JAR file (possibly the code only needs to understand ZIP really).  The server also needs to support the HTTP Range header.  Best example I can find is in C# http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8688/Extracting-files-from-a-remote-ZIP-archive  As for loading the class after you've downloaded the file, I don't know.

Comment: Well, I've figured this much... I am a .net programmer and the applet is going to be used for a jsf website, asp.net and a php. I thought of using a httphandler||Action||Servlet to give the bytes back and use them inside a custom class loader.

Comment: So what are you saying is that there isn't a class loader, or a facility inside Java, which is capable of reading the contents of a remote jar file, given the right permissions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> in an applet, would like to download classes from a Jar file inside
>   the server, but without downloading the whole jar file

If you have control over server code, write a servlet and then call the servlet with appropriate query to  pull the required class in the jar. Something like following:

```
http://myserver.com/myservlet?download_class=x.y.z.class&jar_file=my.jar
```

The applet will call on above URL. At the server, your servlet will pick the jar file and extract the required class and then send it across (using `ServletOutputStream`) to to the applet.

I think above should work for you.

Comment: Thanks I ended up opting for this solution as it is the most elegant one. I am going to create a repository facade in c# in the server, that is going to respond REST requests. As it will be plain vanilla html, I can return a base 64 string with the bytes of that class, for the applet to use. thanks